# Adding entries from multiple MySQL tables using one single SQL join statement, but only if there are entries available in the second table

Tags: mysql, join

Using one single SQL query with a join:
How can I add entries from a second table only if there is a corresponding entry available?

```
project                                source

description   |  source                source_id   |  value
----------------------------           --------------------------------
Project 1     |  1                     1           |  Additional Info 1
Project 2     |  null
```

When I type

```
select project.description, source.value
from project, source
where project.source = source.source_id
and project.description = "Project 1";
```

As desired I receive

```
Project 1   |   Additional Info 1
```

However when I replace `Project 1` with `Project 2` in the last line, I won't get a result, because `project.source` is `null`.
Is it possible to use a single SQL query which outputs something like this?

```
Project 2   |   null
```

I´m looking for  a query which covers both cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` on the `project` table to make sure that *all* projects appear in the result set even if they have no matching `value` in the `source` table.  Projects from the `project` table which do not match will have `NULL` for their `value`.

```
SELECT project.description AS description, source.value AS value
FROM project LEFT JOIN source
ON project.source = source.source_id
```

**Output:**

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| description  |       value        |
---------------+--------------------+
|  Project 1   |  Additional Info 1 |
|  Project 2   |  null              |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Brilliant!
Holy SQL 92 notation.
Originally I prefer the SQL 89 syntax (only with WHERE statements because it´s more logical, but this is great!
Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to help you anyway I can.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use left join....

```
SELECT project.description, source.value FROM project LEFT JOIN source ON project.source = source.source_id;
```